# ejabberd not resolving multiple domains

Tags: configuration, ejabberd

**Intent: Use a single Ubuntu host for hosting multiple chat servers.**

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Server: ejabberd
```

I have a static IP, and am running an Ubuntu VM on VirtualBox on my internal (company) network, and I have port-forwarded all jabber traffic to this Ubuntu machine which is running the ejabberd server.

I also have some domain names: let's call them, example.com, example.net, and example.org. I have added A-records like chat.example.com, chat.example.net, and chat.example.org, and pointed them to my static IP address, and my router in turn is forwarding them to my Ubuntu VM running the ejabberd server. These A-records were added several days back.

I also updated the ejabberd config file to reflect the admin users and the domains like so:

```
%% Admin user
{acl, admin, {user, "najeeb", "chat.example.com"}}.
{acl, admin, {user, "najeeb", "chat.example.net"}}.
{acl, admin, {user, "najeeb", "chat.example.org"}}.

%% Hostname
{hosts, ["localhost", "chat.example.com", "chat.example.net","chat.example.org"]}.
```

And I have also successfully added several users (including user "najeeb") to each of the domains listed above using the ejabberdctl command line utility.

Though I am able to connect to ejabberd using the credentials najeeb@chat.example.com, I am not able to connect to the other chat somains like najeeb@chat.example.net or najeeb@chat.example.org. (I am using Pandion as my client.) However, when I switch the connection settings in my Pandion client to my IP address (as the host), the connection works fine.

I also tried adding entries like so to my /etc/hosts file like so:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       example.com     myhost # myhost is my Ubuntu hostname
127.0.0.1       chat.example.com
127.0.0.1       example.net
127.0.0.1       chat.example.net
127.0.0.1       example.org
127.0.0.1       chat.example.org
```

Trying my best to resolve this, but it's simply no go.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that using the IP address allows you to connect to every domain successfully, it looks to me that your network configuration is incorrect. It seems your /etc/hosts is not taken into account properly.

Note that you have a line showing 127.0.1.1 and the other showing 127.0.0.1.

Are you sure this is correct ?